# ConTeXt: \usemodule [resume] return strange error when lefttext is in used with \starttwocolumns

Tags: context, resume

I don't know where the \starttwocolumns is defined; it seems to work on most occasions but give several unexpected outcome when lefttext option is used.

Is there any easy way to redefine it and insert a blank line at the end of the definition?

```
\usemodule[resume]

\define[2]\roleincompany{{\ssbf #1}\\{\sl #2}\\
\vskip0.8em}

\startresume
\startresumesection[title={Knuth}]
\startresumesubsection[title={Zapf}]

\starttwocolumns
\input ward     % OK
\stoptwocolumns

\starttwocolumns[lefttext=2020]
Anything. Even a blank line will do.
\input ward     % OK
\stoptwocolumns

\starttwocolumns[lefttext=2020]
\roleincompany{My Role}{Company}    % this line mess up with rmsstfbf12pt-rm-tf-012pt-rm-tf-03>modern-designsize-12pt-rm-tf-0-03>modern...
\input ward     % OK
\stoptwocolumns

\starttwocolumns[lefttext=2020]
\input ward  % NOT OK
% problem - tex error       > tex error on line 16 in file virtual://buffer.677>resume.1: ! I can't find file `'.
%<recently read>  
% l.16 \input 
%          ward
% <empty file>
\stoptwocolumns

\stopresumesubsection
\stopresumesection
\stopresume
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** This was a bug in the module, which has been fixed in the version released on 2020.08.07. I am leaving the old answer but this workaround is no longer needed.

I haven't use the `resume` module before, but based on the error message it appears that `\starttwocolumns[lefttext=2020]` is gobbling the first token of the environment. An easy way to prevent that is to add `\relax` after

```
\starttwocolumns[lefttext=2020]\relax
```

I would consider this a bug. Please post this on the context mailing list so that Wolfgang Schuster, who is the author of the module, becomes aware of the bug.

Comment: Adding \relax works and I replace all the additional blank lines I inserted with this to make it explicit.  posted to the mailing list as well. thanks.